# How to combine two or more columns which are giving same information?

Tags: pca, feature-selection, dataset, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing

I am trying to predict the closing price of a cryptocurrency. As its price depends on lots of factors, so I have lots of columns. But a bunch of columns in my dataset are kind of adding the same set of information.

Here is the sample of my dataset, it has 48 columns

#### Dataset

| id | asset_id | open | high | low | volume | market_cap | url_shares | unique_url_shares | reddit_posts | reddit_posts_score | reddit_comments | reddit_comments_score | tweets | tweet_spam | tweet_followers | tweet_quotes | tweet_retweets | tweet_replies | tweet_favorites | tweet_sentiment1 | tweet_sentiment2 | tweet_sentiment3 | tweet_sentiment4 | tweet_sentiment5 | tweet_sentiment_impact1 | tweet_sentiment_impact2 | tweet_sentiment_impact3 | tweet_sentiment_impact4 | tweet_sentiment_impact5 | social_score | average_sentiment | news | price_score | social_impact_score | correlation_rank | galaxy_score | volatility | market_cap_rank | percent_change_24h_rank | volume_24h_rank | social_volume_24h_rank | social_score_24h_rank | medium | youtube | social_volume | percent_change_24h | market_cap_global | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_322qz6 | 1 | 9422.849081 | 9428.490628 | 9422.849081 | 713198620.0 | 173763453624.0 | 1689.0 | 817.0 | 55.0 | 105.0 | 61.0 | 271.0 | 3420.0 | 1671.0 | 11675867.0 | 39.0 | 1343.0 | 448.0 | 2237.0 | 124.0 | 330.0 | 331.0 | 2515.0 | 120.0 | 506133.0 | 1326610.0 | 1159677.0 | 8406185.0 | 281329.0 | 11681999.0 | 3.6 | 69.0 | 2.7 | 3.6 | 3.3 | 66.0 | 0.0071176 | 1.0 | 606.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 5.0 | 4422 | 1.4345161346109587 | 281806567507.0 | 9428.279323 |
| ID_3239o9 | 1 | 7985.359278 | 7992.059917 | 7967.567267 | 400475518.0 | 142694202230.96 | 920.0 | 544.0 | 20.0 | 531.0 | 103.0 | 533.0 | 1491.0 | 242.0 | 5917814.0 | 195.0 | 1070.0 | 671.0 | 3888.0 | 1.0 | 52.0 | 315.0 | 1100.0 | 23.0 | 1320.0 | 381117.0 | 1706376.0 | 3754815.0 | 80010.0 | 5924770.0 | 3.7 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 43.5 | 0.00941863 | 1.0 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2159 | -2.4595073021531104 | 212689713284.66 | 7967.567267 |
| ID_323J9k | 1 | 49202.033778 | 49394.593518 | 49068.057046 | 3017728869.0 | 916697653223.0 | 1446.0 | 975.0 | 72.0 | 1152.0 | 187.0 | 905.0 | 9346.0 | 4013.0 | 47778746.0 | 104.0 | 2014.0 | 1099.0 | 11476.0 | 331.0 | 923.0 | 864.0 | 6786.0 | 442.0 | 9848462.0 | 5178557.0 | 2145663.0 | 25510267.0 | 5110490.0 | 47796942.0 | 3.7 | 22.0 | 3.1 | 3.0 | 3.3 | 65.5 | 0.01353005 | 1.0 | 692.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |  |  | 10602 | 4.942447794031182 | 1530711784042.0 | 49120.738484 |

#### Problem Description

I tried to build a model with just `['open', 'high', 'low', 'market_cap', 'market_cap_global']` columns whose score is quite satisfying, but its not that good.

So I thought to add more columns in model training but the problem is

1. My dataset has a high multicollinearity issue
2. Many columns are adding similar information

For that reason I want to combine some columns for example;

- `col1:` [tweets', 'tweet_spam', tweet_followers', 'tweet_quotes', 'tweet_retweets', 'tweet_replies', 'tweet_favorites']
- `col2:` ['tweet_sentiment1', 'tweet_sentiment2', 'tweet_sentiment3', 'tweet_sentiment4', tweet_sentiment5']
- `col3:` ['tweet_sentiment_impact1', 'tweet_sentiment_impact2', tweet_sentiment_impact3', 'tweet_sentiment_impact4', 'tweet_sentiment_impact5']
- `col4:` ['reddit_posts', 'reddit_posts_score', 'reddit_comments', 'reddit_comments_score']

#### My question

How should I combine those columns should I directly sum it up or is there any rule of thumb that I can follow to do that.

One of the way I was thinking is to take the PCA of those columns and reduce them to 1 for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the clusters of features you've identified do all measure the same underlying property (e.g. twitter sentiment), then yes, combining them by averaging/summing or PCA (which is just a weighted sum) is a very common approach here.

If you want to dig in a little deeper, you might consider trying

- Structural equation modelling to fully specify the relationships between these variables and your outcome
- Exploratory factor analysis (with orthogonal rotation) to properly identify the clusters of predictors that go together and can be combined, along with optimal weights for combining them.
- Using Partial least squares or Supervised principal components analysis as your predictive model. These algorithms do both dimension reduction on the predictors and predictive modelling at the same time.

Most of these methods are more geared towards finding out which variables should be combined. If you already know which variables go together, the correlations are strong, and you've standardised the variables to be on the same scale (e.g. z-scores; and this is important) it doesn't really matter how much you weight each individual variable: the result you get from just summing everything will be very strongly correlated with the result from PCA or other weighting schemes.

Comment: Is PCA enough in my current situtation?

Comment: Usually, yes. I've edited the question to add a point about correlations which I forgot to make.

Comment: As always, if this answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted, and optionally upvote it.